# Trying to assign a character to a string inside a pointer to a struct causes a segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, text-editor

I am trying to develop a simple line-based text editor in C programming language, as I thought it would be a small project and fun to work on at the same time. However, in order to make the editor line based, I first have to convert the file the user is editing from a buffer into a linked list, using '\n' as a delimiting character. However, trying to assign a character to the string inside the pointer to my node structure cases a segmentation fault. Here is the code for the function:

```
void strlink(line_t *dest, char *src) {
    size_t i = 0;
    size_t bufpos = 0;
    line_t *current = dest;

    current = malloc(sizeof(line_t));
    current->linebuf = (char *)malloc(8192);

    while (src[i] != EOF) {
        while (src[i] != '\n') {
            current->linebuf[bufpos] = src[i];
            bufpos++;
        }
        bufpos = 0;
        current->nextline = malloc(sizeof(line_t));
        current->linebuf  = malloc(8192);
        current = current->nextline;
        i++;
    }
    current->nextline->nextline = NULL;
}
```

Originally, I did a few things differently. For one, I assigned to `current->nextline->linebuf` instead of `current->linebuf` because I thought you had to assign to the buffer for the next line. I also stored the string in the structure with a static length of `8192`. Changing it has not helped at all. I also used to put the line where I allocate memory for the structure instance after I got every character from the string, but that caused a segmentation fault on its own and now this solution seems to work for it. However, the true culprit is the line where I try to assign the char to the string. Why is this not working?
(here is my `line_t` struct)

```
typedef struct line {
    char *linebuf;
    struct line *nextline;
} line_t;
```

Comment: This code snippet does not make sense because it invokes a memory leak.
42     current->linebuf = (char *) malloc(8192);
 43 
 44     while(src[i] != EOF) {
 45         while(src[i] != '\n') {
 46             current->linebuf[bufpos] = src[i];
 47             bufpos++;
 48         }
             //...
 51         current->linebuf  = malloc(8192);

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Unfortunately, it turns out I do need to allocate memory for the next line, however, I see I could get rid of the mallocs for the lines, right?

Comment: This statement  current->nextline->nextline = NULL; results in undefined behavior.

Comment: You are allocating memory for current->linebuf  = malloc(8192); two times.

Comment: `while(src[i] != EOF` is strange.  Certainly the calling code would not store an `EOF` in a _string_.  BTW: this is an infinite loop when `char` is _unsigned_. Show the code that assignes `EOF` to the string.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I thought I needed to allocate memory for the new line after I form a string for every line?

Comment: @Safal Aryal The function in whole does not make sense because function parameters are its local variable and changes of the parameter dest do not influence on the original argument. There is nothing to discuss. Rewrite the function anew.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow But the parameters are pointers, and I thought you could modify parameters if they are passed by reference and not by value.

Comment: @Safal Aryal You passed a pointer by value. If you want to pass a pointer by reference when declare the function like void strlink(line_t **dest, char *src);

Comment: @chux I'm trying to append every character in the string to each string in the linked list, and moving onto another node everytime I see the '\n' character. I have a variable called bufpos which gets reset every time an '\n'  is encountered. The EOF is needed because I want to stop reading the characters in the string when I see EOF.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow If I pass them by reference, I can modify them right?

Comment: @SafalAryal Yes, if you pass a pointer by reference then you can modify it (the pointer) within the function.

Comment: EOF is not a char, and cannot be a part of any string. EOF is an int, specifically given a value outside the range of any char, so squeezing it into a char like you're doing changes it into a char with the same lower 8 bits as EOF, which may or may not be perfectly valid character to find in your input.

Comment: @SafalAryal besides, if you read an `EOF` then you won't read anything more because the stream got closed or it reached the end. Adding `EOF` in the buffer makes no sense.